# How to delete a block on block builder?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having trouble finding a way to delete block in my blockbuilder account. It seems whenever I save there will be a copy generated, and if I open the same block on two different screens it will be saved twice. I hope this not a stupid question. Any suggestions will be appreciated!

Comment: Go to GitHub Gist and delete them from there: https://gist.github.com/lydiawawa

Comment: @GerardoFurtado I tried to delete them on GitHub, but the change didn't occur immediately until now. Thank you for all the tips. You are the best!

Comment: I read somewhere that it can take up to 5 minutes for the changes showing up on bl.ocks, but in my experience I've seen the changes occurring almost immediately.